# Wrong module is displayed in next page when using $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Below I have a php script where it displays a "Course" drop down menu and a "Module" Drop down menu. What is suppose to happen is the user first selects a course from the "Course" drop down menu and then a list of Modules which belongs to the selected course will appear in the "Modules" drop down menu. Below is the code for this:

```
create_session.php  



$sql = "SELECT CourseId, CourseNo, CourseName FROM Course"; 

$sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

$sqlstmt->execute(); 

$sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId, $dbCourseNo, $dbCourseName);

$courses = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

$courseHTML = "";  
$courseHTML .= '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
{ 
    $courseno = $dbCourseNo;
    $course = $dbCourseId;
    $coursename = $dbCourseName; 
    $courseHTML .= "<option value='".$course."'>" . $courseno . " - " . $coursename . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  
} 

$courseHTML .= '</select>'; 

?>


<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Course: <?php echo $courseHTML; ?>
                <input id="courseSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $submittedCourseId = $_POST['courses'];

    $query = "SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, c.CourseNo, m.ModuleNo,
            c.CourseName,
            m.ModuleName
            FROM Course c
            INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
            JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
            WHERE
            (c.CourseId = ?)
            ORDER BY c.CourseName, m.ModuleId";

    $qrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);

    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $qrystmt->bind_param("s",$submittedCourseId);
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

    $qrystmt->execute(); 

    $qrystmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseNo,$dbModuleNo,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);

    $qrystmt->store_result();

    $num = $qrystmt->num_rows();

    if($num ==0){
        echo "<p style='color: red'>Please Select a Course</p>";
    } else { 

        $dataArray = array();

        while ( $qrystmt->fetch() ) { 
            // data array
            $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['CourseName'] = $dbCourseName; 
            $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['CourseNo'] = $dbCourseNo; 
            $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['Modules'][$dbModuleId]['ModuleName'] = $dbModuleName; 
            $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['Modules'][$dbModuleId]['ModuleNo'] = $dbModuleNo; 

            // session data
            $_SESSION['idcourse'] = $dbCourseNo;
            $_SESSION['namecourse'] = $dbCourseName;
            $_SESSION['idmodule'] = $dbModuleNo;
            $_SESSION['namemodule'] = $dbModuleName;

            }

        foreach ($dataArray as $foundCourse => $courseData) {

            $output = ""; 

            $output .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseData['CourseNo'] .  " - "  . $courseData['CourseName'] . "</p>";

            $moduleHTML = ""; 
            $moduleHTML .= '<select name="module" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
            $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;      
            foreach ($courseData['Modules'] as $moduleId => $moduleData) {        

                $moduleHTML .= "<option value='$moduleId'>" . $moduleData['ModuleNo'] . " - " . $moduleData['ModuleName'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
            } 
        }
    $moduleHTML .= '</select>';

    echo $output;

?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Course: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?>
                <input id="courseSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

So lets say I select the Course `INFO101 - Information Communication Technology` in the "Course" drop down menu, it displays the following modules in the Module drop down menu below which corresponds with that course:

```
CHI2520 - Advanced Web Programming
CHI2220 - Systems Strategy
CHI2350 - Interactive Systems
```

Now this is the problem I have. If I select the module `CHI2520 - Advanced Web Programming` and then access the page below, it displays this module instead `CHI2350 - Interactive Systems`.

QandATable.php:

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['idmodule'])) {

        $_SESSION['idmodule'] = $_POST['idmodule'];

    }

    if (isset($_POST['namemodule'])) {

        $_SESSION['namemodule'] = $_POST['namemodule'];

    }

if (isset($_POST['idcourse'])) {

$_SESSION['idcourse'] = $_POST['idcourse'];

}

if (isset($_POST['namecourse'])) {

$_SESSION['namecourse'] = $_POST['namecourse'];

}


    $outputDetails = "";
    $outputDetails .= "
    <table id='sessionDetails' border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Course:</th> 
    <th>{$_SESSION['idcourse']}  {$_SESSION['namecourse']}</th>
    </tr>
<tr>
<th>Module:</th> 
<th>{$_SESSION['idmodule']}  {$_SESSION['namemodule']}</th>
</tr>
    </table>
    ";

    echo $outputDetails;

    ?>
```

My question is that why does it display the wrong module number and name in the other page? Both page does include `session_start();`

Below is form which navigates to QandATable.php:

```
<form action="QandATable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">
            <table><tr><th>6: Module:</th>
            <td><?php echo $moduleHTML; ?></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <p><strong>11: </strong><input class="questionBtn" type="submit" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion" /></p>   


        </form>
```

Comment: You are building `$dataArray` as a 2D array, but storing values into `$_SESSION` in that fetch loop overwriting on each iteration. Do you mean to store those as an array too?

Comment: What is your code/form that posts to `QandATable.php`? You are checking `if (isset($_POST[...]))` to rest `$_SESSION[...]`, put the only code/form you show is `<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">` and it only fields `<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop">` OR `<select name="module" id="modulesDrop">`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yeah that is pretty much what I am saying

Comment: @sean I included the form which simply contains the list of modules in a drop down menu and then submittied to QandATable.php at bottom of question

Comment: You are checking for `isset($_POST['idmodule'])` & `isset($_POST['namemodule'])` to change your `$_SESSION['idmodule']` & `$_SESSION['namemodule']`, but you don't have any form elements with `name="idmodule"` OR `name="namemodule"` so it will always revert back to the preset `$_SESSION['idmodule']` & `$_SESSION['namemodule']`. Where did `$_POST['idmodule']` & `$_POST['namemodule']` come from?

Comment: @Sean I haven't got a name attribute that is either `idmodule` or `namemodule`, but then I don't have a name attribute for either `idcourse` or `namecourse` yet that works very well

Comment: @Sean I updated code so you can see whole code but it is strange as like you said you can see why idmodule and namemodule shouldn't work when posting them but idcourse and namecourse works with no problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign [php sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) once the page is loaded already! Well you could but not just with php itself! let me explain:

- first request ( the form gets downloaded - no modules displayed )
- second request ( new form gets downloaded - based on the courseid which has been submitted you display the right modules )
- third request ( based on the moduleid submitted you have to populate php sessions for later use )

What you were trying to do is to populate the session vars during the second request... however, there's no way you could ever retrieve the right moduleid by doing so! Only the browser and eventually javascript know what's selected at that specific point in time when the page is living just inside the browser!

What you actually did, as i just said, is to write your sessions in the second request. **That means that you wrote your session vars prior to the user's module selection!** And what you put to session was nothing more than the last fetched result row in the loop! That is the reason why you always had the last module in your session, which in your case was `Interactive Systems`!

### Let's find a solution now

Provided your course / module selector works properly, displaying the right modules once the users selects its course, you just have to make your third request!

```
<form name="moduleid" [...] >

    <option value="[moduleid]> [moduleno] - [modulename] </option>
    
    [...]
    
</form>
```

Based on a structure like this... i just guess this is what your module form could look like... you have to perform the third request to the server which can be either on the same page, as you did for adding the modules select, or on an another one! **the clue code here is something like the one below**... you don't even have to generate any output ;)

```
if ( isset($_POST['moduleid']) )
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select moduleno, modulename from  module where moduleid = ?');
    
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['moduleid'] );
    
    if ( $stmt->execute() )
    {   
            $stmt->bind_result($moduleno, $modulename); $stmt->fetch();

        $_SESSION['moduleid'] = $_POST['moduleid'];
        $_SESSION['moduleno'] = $moduleno;
        $_SESSION['modulename'] = $modulename;
    }
}
```

if your course / module selector does not work properly... reffer to my other answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what you omitted from the original script here but your problem seems to reinforce that using sessions and post vars might be tricky if not done properly! each of the two methods have a really specific purpose [as you can read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559655/when-to-use-url-session-cookie-variables). For the information you gave us, post vars would be more than enough though :)

there is somewhere in your script where you reassign session vars every time the loop cycles. that means that only the last "module" will be stored in your session:

```
$_SESSION['idcourse'] = $dbCourseNo;
$_SESSION['namecourse'] = $dbCourseName;
$_SESSION['idmodule'] = $dbModuleNo;
$_SESSION['namemodule'] = $dbModuleName;
```

On the other hand, however, you're not using sessions anywhere in this code... so they might be useless or irrelevant ( at least on this pages )!

other than that there's no need for doing strange things in your action!

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

that does exactly the same thing ;) and does not involve any php!

what else... well the problem could be in your query as well, retrieving corrupted information from your database!

---

### Here's a quick solution

There might be some errors... i havent run the script yet! I have no webserver aviable, my bad... but you might catch one of the ways this ment to be done! Its just to give you an idea, because you dont really need that whole session overhead for that ;) i've even changed your second query a bit ... its very likely that you dont need to join three tables as well! actually **course_modules** and **module** give you all the information needed, provided you get the courseid from the previous form submission!

just run the first query every time... joining three tables isnt faster than making to easier queries.. that said... here's the code :P hope this helped!

```
<?php $_courseid = isset($_POST['courseid']) ? $_POST['courseid'] : null; ?>

<!-- action filled only for validation purpose, all browsers will reload the same page by default -->

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">

    <!-- you should be using tables for tabular data only -->

    Course: 

    <!-- using onchange is user friendly -->

    <select name="courseid" id="coursesDrop" onchange="this.form.submit()">

    <?php if ( !isset($_courseid) ): ?>

        <option selected>Please Select</option>

    <?php endif; 

    $result = $mysqli->query('select courseid, courseno, coursename from course');

    while( list($courseid, $courseno, $coursename) = $result->fetch_array() ): ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $courseid ?>" <?php if ($_courseid == $courseid) echo "selected" ?>>

            <?php echo "{$courseno} - {$coursename}" ?>

        </option>

    <?php endwhile; $result->free(); ?> 

    </select>            

    <?php if ( isset($_courseid) ): ?>

    <select name="module" id="modulesDrop">   

        <option selected>Please Select</option>         

        <?php $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select m.moduleid, moduleno, modulename form `course_module` join `module` m using(moduleid) where courseid = ? order by m.moduleid');

        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_courseid);

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->store_result();

        while( list($moduleid, $moduleno, $modulename) = $result->fetch_array() ): ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $moduleid ?>"><?php echo "{$moduleno} - {$modulename}" ?></option>

        <?php endwhile; $result->free(); $stmt->close(); ?>

        </select>

    <? endif; ?>

</form>
```

Comment: If you can fix this then I will award you bounty points because I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: All I want to do is  what do I write in the other php script (QandATable.php) in order to be able to display the correct module name and number on that page, that is all I am asking. At the moment you have not displayed anything for the QandATable.php script. Please read the question again and you will understand :)

Comment: There's nothing more than what you asked in your question written here! modules get updated according to the course selected! there's nothing more in your question... it probably has been edited :)

Comment: My mistake, it has been editted, I must of editted the wrong question, I have performed a roll back to display the full question again. Please read the question again :)

Comment: ok, lets try again... does the first page actually work (i mean just the dropdown itself)? if so just take what i wrote above as a suggestion for optimizing your code! however, if you want to write something to your php session once the user selects a module you have to run ANOTHER request to actually write the sessions!

Comment: @user1819709 i wrote another answer as this rolled back one is miles away from the original one xD it actually asks two different things though ;)